# エラー：SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)

Tags: android, sqlite

データベースのバージョンを変更し、データベースのアップグレードをしようとしたところ以下のようなエラーメッソージが返ってきました。
「android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode」
色々調べて、データベースをcloseしてみてもうまくいきません。（closeの仕方が間違っているのかもしれませんが...）
下記にコードを記載します。
現在setDataToDBメソッドの中でエラーが出ています。
すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_MAN + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VOICE TEXT)");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_WOMAN + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VOICE TEXT)");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_WOMAN_MAX + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VOICE TEXT)");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_WOMAN_MAX + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VOICE TEXT)");
            }finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
            setDataToDB("aaa", "bbb", Uri.parse("content://taro.thanks.MyContentProvider/" + TB_MAN));
            setDataToDB("AAA", "BBB", Uri.parse("content://taro.thanks.MyContentProvider/" + TB_MAN_MAX));
            setDataToDB("ccc", "ddd", Uri.parse("content://taro.thanks.MyContentProvider/" + TB_WOMAN));
            setDataToDB("CCC", "DDD", Uri.parse("content://taro.thanks.MyContentProvider/" + TB_WOMAN_MAX));
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_MAN);
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_WOMAN);
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_MAN_MAX);
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_WOMAN_MAX);
            }finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void setDataToDB(String defaultData1, String defaultData2, Uri uri) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_VOICE, defaultData1);
            values.put(COLUMN_VOICE, defaultData2);
            getContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 今回の問題とは関連は無さそうですが、「try 〜 finally」で実行している db.execSQL(...) の最後に db.setTransactionSuccessful(); を入れておいた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りsetTransactionSuccessful()を追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android開発初心者向け - Content Providerの使い方](http://qiita.com/rayc5/items/1457331992e1eb02b29f#sqliteopenhelper-basecolumns)を読みつつ、
勉強させていただいている中で気づいたのですが、
`setDataToDB`で使用しているContent Providerの`insert()`の実装で
`SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase()`みたいなことを
していませんか。

DBHelperは複数のDBインタンスを中に持てないため、
質問にあるような実装をDBHelper内で行うと、DBのインスタンスが複数→lockかかってるからエラーで落とすわとなります。おそらく。

対処としては`onCreate`の中に`setDataToDB`の処理を書かないで
外に実装を出すことかなぁ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。onCreateの中のsetDataToDBを外に出すことで動きました！理由はわからないですが、ともかく先に進めて本当にうれしいです！

Comment: おお、Content Providerがヌルポで嵌ってた人ですね。昨日の今日と困難続きですが、是非頑張って下さい。
解決方法はともかく、解説は間違ってると思うので、何方か詳細の説明と、編集・訂正をお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`close`を試したということは、どこかの`Activity`でも`SQLiteOpenHelper`インスタンスを生成していて、かつ`ContentProvider`でもインスタンスを生成しているということでしょうか。

とすると`SQLiteOpenHelper`のインスタンスが複数生成され、それぞれがトランザクションを確保しているためにロックが掛かっているだけだと思います。

解決策としては、

1. `MyDBHelper`をシングルトンにして`Application`内で使いまわす
2. `MyDBHelper`を直接扱わず、常に`ContentProvider`を経由する

この場合、`ContentProvider`を利用されているので、2.がいいと思います。

また、`MyDBHelper#onCreate()`でやっているテーブルの初期値の`insert`は、`ContentProvider`を経由させず、テーブル生成のトランザクション内で直接行うべきだと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。MyDBHelperのonCreate内のsetDataToDBメソッドをActivity側から呼び出すことで解決することができました。（理由はよくわからないのですが^^;）また、insertはテーブル生成のトランザクションで直接行うべきということは知らなかったので、これからそういった実装をしていこうと思います。この度はありがとうございました。